# Android registration form using HTTP Post, Java, Json, PHP

Tags: java, php, android, json, post

I'm trying to register users to my web hosted SQL database. The java application will hopefully POST the values over to the web to be formatted before being put into an SQL statement.

Below is my code to process the POST request on the server.

```
$password=$_POST["password"]; 
$username=$_POST["username"]; 
$first = $_POST["first"];
$second = $_POST["second"];
$password = sha1($password);

$query = "INSERT INTO plateusers (email, password, first, second) 
      VALUES ('$username','$password', '$first', '$second')";

       if ($query_run = mysqli_query($mysqli_conn, $query)) {
                $response["success"] = 1;
                  $response["message"] = "You have been registered"; 
                  die(json_encode($response));
       } 
       else 
           { 
                $response["success"] = 0;
                $response["message"] = "Invalid details";
                die(json_encode($response));
           } 
           mysql_close();
```

Firstly I am aware of my statement being open to injection however security will come after it working.

I then created a form for users to input their details in my RegisterActivity, the code for that is:

```
public class RegisterActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Context c;
EditText eTEmail;
EditText eTPassword;
EditText eTFname;
EditText eTSname;

ImageButton iBLogin;
String password;
String email;
String fname;
String sname;
String url = "*******";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    c = this;

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    //Casting
    eTEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTEmail);
    eTPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTPassword);
    eTFname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTFname);
    eTSname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTSname);
    iBLogin = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.iBLogin);

    iBLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //  _("Login button hit");

            email = eTEmail.getText() + "";
            fname = eTFname.getText() + "";
            sname = eTSname.getText() + "";
            password = eTPassword.getText() + "";

            if (sname.length() == 0 || fname.length() == 0 || email.length() == 0 || password.length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(c, "Please fill in all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if (sname.length() > 0 && fname.length() > 0 && email.length() > 0 && password.length() > 0) {
                //Do networking
                Networking n = new Networking();
                n.execute(url, Networking.NETWORK_STATE_REGISTER);
            }

        }
    });
}


//AsyncTask good for long running tasks
public class Networking extends AsyncTask {

    public static final int NETWORK_STATE_REGISTER = 1;

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {

        getJson((String) params[0], (Integer) params[1]);
        return null;
    }
}

private void getJson(String url, int state) {
    //Do a HTTP POST, more secure than GET
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
    List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    boolean valid = false;

    switch (state) {
        case Networking.NETWORK_STATE_REGISTER:
            //Building key value pairs to be accessed on web
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", email));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("first", fname));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("second", sname));

            valid = true;


            break;
        default:
            // Toast.makeText(c, "Unknown state", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    if (valid == true) {
        //Reads everything that comes from server
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
        try {
            UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
            request.setEntity(entity);

            //Send off to server
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

            //Reads response and gets content
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            String line = "";
            String LineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            //Read back server output
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(line + LineSeparator);
            }

            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Toast.makeText(c, "Error during networking", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        decodeResultIntoJson(stringBuffer.toString());

        //Toast.makeText(c, "Valid details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        //Toast.makeText(c, "Invalid details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}

private void decodeResultIntoJson(String response) {
    /* Example from server
    {
       "success":1,
       "message":"You have been successfully registered"
    }
     */
    if (response.contains("error")) {
        try {
            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(response);
            String error = jo.getString("error");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    try {
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(response);

        String success = jo.getString("success");
        String message = jo.getString("message");
       // Toast.makeText(c, "Register successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

This is my first attempt at developing an Android application, any help will be appreciated thanks.

**Url** variable has been commented out for obvious reasons, it links to the php script mentioned above.

When run there seems to be no addition to the database, however running the script alone will allow input into the database I think there is a problem POSTing the data

Comment: Are you sure that your PHP script is getting the POST data ? What exactly is not working in your application ?

Comment: Firstly trying to register a user to the database would be great. I'm not sure the PHP script is getting the post data, because there was no input into the database. However without taking data from POST the script does  input into the database

Comment: In that case, the first thing that you might want to verify is that the PHP script is actually getting the form data. If the script is not getting the data then there is no way that data can be entered in the database. Try var_dump($_POST); at the top of the php script maybe? Also make sure the PHP error reporting is turned on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making sure my application could connect to the internet solved the problem. This was a problem I didn't know I had until I found the appropiate code to fix the problem.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```